# Is there a way to use excel power query to query a SAS dataset on a local drive?

Tags: excel, sas, powerquery

I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find an answer so hopefully someone here can assist. We have a SAS program set to run weekly that is outputting a dataset to a local drive. Is there a way to get excel Power Query to see it? I can connect to datassets fine that are housed within the database but stored locally is an issue. Outputting this to the database isn't an option for us. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the Stored Process server you can create a web query to access it, as described here:  https://www.rawsas.com/sas-as-a-service-an-easy-way-to-get-sas-into-excel-power-bi-and-000s-of-other-tools-languages/

This functionality also comes bundled with https://datacontroller.io (free for up to 10 users)

Disclosure - I wrote the blog and created the product.

Alternatives:

- update your job to export your data as CSV or some other format that can be read natively by excel.
- Use the IOM interface and VBA
- SAS Addin for excel

All these options require server SAS.  In short, there is no way that Excel Power Query can connect *directly* to a SAS dataset on a local drive, as the .sas7bdat format is a proprietary SAS format optimised for use by SAS.